# Connect to the Outlook of another user over the Internet

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

I am developing a program that shows the outlook sent and inbox statistics using c#.

To access Outlook I put the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook reference in my c# application.

My question is how can I connect with another user. I am able to connect with my deskop application user. The code I have used is pasted below:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder sentFolder = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = null;
        MAPIFolder inboxChild = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxChildChild = null;

        app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        ns.Logon("xxxxx","xxxxx", false, false); 
    }
```

İn ns.Logon("xxxxx","xxxxx", false, false);  line I connect with another user but the application always connects with the desktop user.

How i connect with another user?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an instance of outlook.exe running on another machine? Or an Exchange mailbox owned by another domain user?

In the latter case you can use `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder` in the Outlook Object Model.

If using Redemption (I am its author) is an option, you can also use [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetSharedMailbox` or `GetSharedDefaultFolder`. [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` is another option.